# HttpContext.Current.Session null on page rendering when im adding CustomUrlAuthorizationModule tag to web.config

Tags: session, url, module, null, authorization

Dear,
I'm facing a problem with `HttpContext.Current.Session` when I'm adding `CustomUrlAuthorizationModule` tag to web.config. 
Every time i'm adding the above tag to my web.config, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null every time the page is rendered.

PS: i'm using `HttpContext.Current.Session` from `SQLSiteMapProvider` class from `BuiltSiteMap`() function.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advanced,
Regards,
Jad